# Как вывести строку средствами биос assembler

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Мне нужно вывести строку средствами `BIOS` использую `fasm`. Проблема в том что выводить так как показано в коде не очень хочется, очень долго. дос инты не предлагать, т.к. он сохраняется как `.bin` и делается загрузочным `.iso` файлом.

```
mov ah , 0x0e
mov al , "H"
int 0x10
mov al , "e"
int 0x10
mov al , "l"
int 0x10
mov al , "l"
int 0x10
mov al , "o"
int 0x10
mov al , ","
int 0x10
mov al , " "
int 0x10
mov al , "w"
int 0x10
mov al , "o"
int 0x10
mov al , "r"
int 0x10
mov al , "l"
int 0x10
mov al , "d"
int 0x10
mov al , "!"

jmp $
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: А зачем использовать именно bios. пишите напрямую в видеопамять. 0xB800:0000

Comment: Ну сделайте цикл - загрузка очередного символа и вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Все это можно сделать в отдельной подпрограмме:

```
  print:
    push ax bx   ;Сохраняем старое значение ax и bx в стеке
    mov ah, 0x0E
  .lp:
    mov al, [si] ;В si хранится адрес строки
    cmp al, 0x00 ;Если текущий символ 0, то ...
    je .end      ;... конец
    mov bl, 0x02 ;Цвет буквы
    int 0x10      
    inc si       ;Увеличиваем указатель на строку на 1
    jmp .lp
  .end:
    pop bx ax    ;Загружаем старое значение ax и bx обратно
    ret          ;Выход из программы
```

Пример использования:

```
...

mov si, hello_msg
call print

...

hello_msg db 'Hello world!', 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00 ;0x0A - перенос каретки (на след. строку)
                                              ;0x0D - возвращение каретки в начальное положение (по горизонтали)
                                              ;0x00 - символ конца строки
```